# Parsing a file containing multiple JSON objects separated by blank lines or tabs

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am having trouble trying to get JSON parsed correctly here. I have the following format and tried using JObjects, but what it does is split one object into its different objects. Perhaps an example will make sense:

```
{
  "completed_in": 0.012,
  "max_id": 136536013832069120,
  "max_id_str": "136536013832069120",
  "next_page": "?page=2&max_id=136536013832069120&q=twitterapi&rpp=1",
  "page": 1,
  "query": "twitterapi",
  "refresh_url": "?since_id=136536013832069120&q=twitterapi",
  "results": [
  {
  "created_at": "Tue, 15 Nov 2011 20:08:17 +0000",
  "from_user": "fakekurrik",
  "from_user_id": 370773112,
  "from_user_id_str": "370773112",
  "from_user_name": "fakekurrik",
  "geo": null,
  "id": 136536013832069120,
  "id_str": "136536013832069120",
  "iso_language_code": "en",
  "metadata": {
    "result_type": "recent"
  },
  "profile_image_url": "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1540298033/phatkicks_normal.jpg",
  "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/&quot;&gt;web&lt;/a&gt;",
  "text": "@twitterapi, keep on keeping it real",
  "to_user": "twitterapi",
  "to_user_id": 6253282,
  "to_user_id_str": "6253282",
  "to_user_name": "Twitter API"
  }
],
"results_per_page": 1,
 "since_id": 0,
 "since_id_str": "0"
}
```

This is what I consider one object. I have files that have hundreds of these and just separated by a tab or blank line. Now if I use JObject

```
   Dim jobj As JObject = JObject.Parse(txtStuff.ToString())

    Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jobj.Children().ToList
```

Results contains all the individual tokens. How can I get each object like the above (the entire object) into a list to process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're really asking two questions here.

1. Given the above JSON, how do I get the data into a nice object structure?
2. Given that I have files containing lots of these objects, how do I get them into a list?

The first part is very easy.  Just define a class structure that matches your JSON, then use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` to deserialize the JSON into that object.  For the JSON you posted, the class structure would look something like this:

```
Class RootObject
    Public Property completed_in As Double
    Public Property max_id As Long
    Public Property max_id_str As String
    Public Property next_page As String
    Public Property page As Integer
    Public Property query As String
    Public Property refresh_url As String
    Public Property results As List(Of Result)
    Public Property results_per_page As Integer
    Public Property since_id As Integer
    Public Property since_id_str As String
End Class

Class Result
    Public Property created_at As String
    Public Property from_user As String
    Public Property from_user_id As Integer
    Public Property from_user_id_str As String
    Public Property from_user_name As String
    Public Property geo As Object
    Public Property id As Long
    Public Property id_str As String
    Public Property iso_language_code As String
    Public Property metadata As Metadata
    Public Property profile_image_url As String
    Public Property source As String
    Public Property text As String
    Public Property to_user As String
    Public Property to_user_id As Integer
    Public Property to_user_id_str As String
    Public Property to_user_name As String
End Class

Class Metadata
    Public Property result_type As String
End Class
```

You can deserialize it like this:

```
Dim obj As String = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(json)
```

So at this point, `obj` will contain all the data from one object as you have defined it in your question.  Now, you have indicated that you have a file that has many of these JSON objects together separated by a tab or a blank line.  You can't just read the whole file in and give it to the JSON parser as one big string because this format isn't valid JSON.  (Each individual object is valid JSON of course, but when strung together with tabs or blank line separators, the whole is not valid.)  So, you will need to read the file in, line by line (or perhaps character by character) to find the separators and break it up into valid JSON objects that the parser *can* understand.  Each time you find a separator, take all the data that you've read since the last separator and feed that to the deserializer.  The result of each deserialization will be a valid `RootObject` which you can then add to a list as you go along.

Here is some code to give you an idea of how this might work.  You may have to tweak it, depending on your needs, but I'm guessing it's not that far off the mark.

```
'' This function will read a file containing a series of JSON objects separated by 
'' some string that is NOT part of the JSON.  Could be a blank line or a tab or 
'' something else.  It will return a list of the deserialized JSON objects.
'' This function relies on two other helper functions (below).
Function ReadJsonFile(fileName As String, separator As String) As List(Of RootObject)
    Dim objects As New List(Of RootObject)
    Using sr As New StreamReader(fileName)
        Dim json As String
        Do
            json = ReadToSeparator(sr, separator)
            If json.Length > 0 Then
                objects.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(json))
            End If
        Loop Until json.Length = 0
    End Using
    Return objects
End Function

'' This function will read and build up a string until the given separator is found.
'' Once the separator is found, it returns the string with the separator removed.
'' If no separator is found before the end of the data is reached, it returns
'' whatever was read to that point.
Function ReadToSeparator(reader As TextReader, separator As String) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    While reader.Peek <> -1
        Dim ch As Char = ChrW(reader.Read())
        sb.Append(ch)
        If TailMatchesSeparator(sb, separator) Then
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - separator.Length, separator.Length)
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function

'' This function checks whether the last characters in a StringBuffer match the
'' given separator string.  Returns true if so or false if not.
Function TailMatchesSeparator(sb As StringBuilder, separator As String) As Boolean
    If sb.Length >= separator.Length Then
        Dim i As Integer = sb.Length - 1
        For j As Integer = separator.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If sb(i) <> separator(j) Then
                Return False
            End If
            i = i - 1
        Next
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

To use this, just call `ReadJsonFile`, passing a file name and a separator string.  For example:

```
Dim separator As String = vbCrLf + vbCrLf
Dim objects As List(Of RootObject) = ReadJsonFile("json.txt", separator)
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond and the detailed answer. I appreciate. Yes since my post I searched and tried multiple options and could not find the json.net soln that would just split the objects as I wanted and found that deserializing it would be the best choice. I then made the error of not defining the class structure to each field but what you provided definitely will help. thanks